# Custom dimension on product pages from h1 using GTM - what's the best tagging strategy for the tag to only fire on the product pages?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm able to get the product tag to fire, extract the product name from h1 and pass it onto as a custom dimension.

However, as it's a different tag from the main page views tag - I would get duplicate page views.

What would be the best strategy in tagging the custom dimensions?

Would creating an exception so the main page views tag don't run on the product pages and then creating that product page tag that only runs on product pages be acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you add the payload data to a non-interaction event instead. This way, you do not inflate your page view numbers.

But - if you want to add this information to the page itself, then you'd need to set it up as a page view. It all depends on what you want to achieve.

Otherwise, I'd write a JS snippet that just checks the URL and then decides what to fire. Or, use a hit- or eventCallback. Many different ways to solve a problem!